# Android Annotations: custom view inheritance?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-annotations

I'm trying to create a custom view that has a content area and a progress bar so that any inheriting custom view would have it's layout inflated in the content area. That way you could show/hide the progress bar on the child view.

```
@EViewGroup(R.layout.loading_view)
class LoadingView extends RelativeLayout{

       // some code

       @ViewById FrameLayout content;
       @ViewById ProgressBar pb;

       public View getFrameLayout(){
              // sub-classes will use this to inject their content 
              return content; 
       }

       void setIsLoading(boolean l){
              // shows\hides pb
       }
}

@EViewGroup(R.layout.other_view)
class OtherView extends LoadingView{
       @ViewById TextView someTxt;

       public OtherView(...){
              // inject to getFrameLayout()
       }

}
```

Now this doesn't remotely work. Here is why:

- `@EViewGroup` on `OtherView` overrides the one on `LoadingView` so `R.layout.loading_view` doesn't even gets loaded. it only gets loaded if you specify `@EViewGroup(R.layout.loading_view)`

  - if you do specify the same layout , there is no point in having `Android Annotations` in the first place since it will not inject view in `OtherView`.

Is there any way at all to make this work ? Any ideas ?

Comment: You could remove @EViewGroup from child and make getFrameLayout abstract. This way each child would return an inflated layout in its getFrameLayout method implementation.

Comment: But then what's the benefit of using AA ?

Comment: Actually, your approach has no sense for me. You want to extend a view class but preserving the parent. However, each one has its own layout. I think the solution is composition, not inheritance, in this case.

Comment: so how would you suggest doing this ?

Comment: i totally agree with @bigdestroyer. The OtherView has the code to deal with its children, and LoadingView has the code to deal with that's children, OtherView included. You an put OtherView to loading_view.xml, then inject it in LoadingView with `@ViewById`.

Comment: The whole point was to make it reusable so that i only have to code it once

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly, you could solve overriding the method:

```
    @EViewGroup(R.layout.loading_view)
    class LoadingView extends RelativeLayout {

       // some code

       @ViewById FrameLayout content;
       @ViewById ProgressBar pb;

       public View getFrameLayout(){
           return content;
       }

       void setIsLoading(boolean l){
              // shows\hides pb
       }
}
```

And each child implement the method returning its content:

```
class OtherView extends LoadingView {
       @ViewById TextView someTxt;

       @Override
       public View getFrameLayout() {
           View content = inflate(R.layout.other_view);
           return content;
       }

}
```

As you said, If you put `@EViewGroup(R.layout.other_view)` in child class, AndroidAnnotations overwrite the main layout view.

Comment: I think an abstract class cannot extend a regular class , it's giving me `class or interface expected` and `annotations not allowed here`

Comment: It seems that AA doesn't support that. Edited.

Comment: `Error:(35, 5) error: @org.androidannotations.annotations.AfterViews can only be used in a class annotated with @org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EViewGroup, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EView, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EBean, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EFragment.`

Comment: Is that error in this classes? Please, post your whole classes, I don't see @AfterViews in this code.

Comment: excuse me it's `@ViewById` that is the problem. not `@AfterViews`

Comment: `Error:(17, 5) error: @org.androidannotations.annotations.ViewById can only be used in a class annotated with @org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EViewGroup, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EView, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EBean, @org.androidannotations.annotations.EFragment.`

Comment: My bad. Child class contains a @ViewById, so yes... it has sense. Try to put @EViewGroup without annotation value in `OtherView`. Just `@EViewGroup`

Comment: overrides the value in `LoadingView` with nothing

Comment: Well... You can obtain the view from the inflated `content`, by `findViewById`. Seems that AA, is not being too util >.<

Comment: Yep. The worst is that I have suffered this kind of problems with AA sometimes. I wonder and wander, but no... -.-

Comment: Guys, i am a maintainer of AA. If you feel we have a missing feature, please open a feature request in GitHub. We also gladly welcome code contributions. :)